# Does WordPress default CSS have Grids?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, css

WordPress 'out of the box' comes with some javascript to allow you to send AJAX requests, show the image select dialog, etc.

Does WordPress 'out of the box' come with any default CSS? Especially for use in themes? As an example, does it have its own Grid CSS setup where I can create grids without needing an external dependency like Bootstrap Twitter?

**Usecase:**
I am developing a simple plugin similar to `Visual Composer`. It will allow the user to create HTML components. If WordPress has default CSS for grids, I can create the HTML components using that grid CSS rather than relying on Bootstrap Twitter (which could conflict with the users theme).

Comment: WordPress doesn't have any default CSS. What do you mean by out of the box CSS? Did you mean the default theme?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does not have a default grid framework in CSS. If you are interested in using [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) or another grid framework, perhaps [Susy](https://github.com/oddbird/susy), then do so and have your plugin write specific IDs and classes that are unique.

Looking at the *Visual Composer* [intro video](https://vc.wpbakery.com/) it appears that they are(must be) using specific IDs and classes for the content that is created with the plugin.

This so that in fact it does not conflict with the current theme. Imagine you use Bootstrap for the generated code of your plugin and someone is using a theme based on Bootstrap.

So whatever you do, make sure that the content your plugin creates, the IDs and classes it makes, is unique. Perhaps even use JS to add random numbers to your classes and IDs to make sure they are unique. That would also mean CSS creation for those unique IDs and classes.